# How to dynamically add columns based on source columns in spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need the updatedDF  as per new columns. but it is not updated with new columns , it still gives me old columns and its names

```
val schema = "sku_cd#sku_code,ean_nbr#ean,vnr_cd#nan_key,dsupp_pcmdty_desc#pack_descr" 

val schemaArr = schema.split(",")

var df = spark.sql("""select sku_code, ean , nan_key, pack_descr from db.products""")

val updatedDF = populateAttributes(df,schemaArr)


 def populateAttributes(df:DataFrame,schemaArr:Array[String]) : DataFrame = {
 for(i <- schemaArr)
    {
          val targetCol = i.split("#")(0)
          val sourceCol = i.split("#")(1)
          df.withColumn(targetCol, col(sourceCol))
     }
      df
   }
```

I get below output which is incorrect

```
 scala> updatedDF.printSchema
 root
 |-- sku_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ean: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nan_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pack_descr: string (nullable = true)
```

Expected output

```
 |-- sku_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ean_nbr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vnr_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dsupp_pcmdty_desc: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the dataframe in your for loop. The line:

```
df.withColumn(targetCol, col(sourceCol))
```

will create a new dataframe and `df` will remain the same.

You can use `var` in order to reassign the original dataframe in each iteration. Also use `withColumnRenamed` to rename a column:

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed(sourceCol, targetCol)
```

Or better, use `foldLeft` :

```
def populateAttributes(df:DataFrame,schemaArr:Array[String]) : DataFrame = {

 schemaArr.foldLeft(df)((acc, m) => {
     val mapping = m.split("#")
     acc.withColumnRenamed(mapping(1), mapping(0))
 })
}
```

---

Another way using a select expression :

```
val selectExpr = schemaArr.map(m => {
  val mapping = m.split("#")
  col(mapping(1)).as(mapping(0))
})

val updatedDF = df.select(selectExpr:_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do what  [blackbishop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386551/blackbishop)  did

```
val schema = "sku_cd#sku_code,ean_nbr#ean,vnr_cd#nan_key,dsupp_pcmdty_desc#pack_descr" 

val schemaArr = schema.split(",").toSeq

val outputDF=schemaArr.foldLeft(inputDF)((df,x)=>df.withColumnRenamed(x,x.split('#')(0)))
```